# Android LinearLayout with Button and FrameLayout using the Maximum Height

Tags: android, button, height, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

I am trying to make a `layout` where there are a `LinearLayout` and inside it I want a `FrameLayout` and a `button`.

I want the `button` to use the bottom of the `linearlayout` and to use the maximum width and the enough height for the button, using wrap content.

The other component, the `FrameLayout` I want to use it the remaining part of the screen.

How can I do it?

Here it the layout so far..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"

      android:orientation="vertical" >

         <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_capture"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:onClick="snapIt"
            android:text="@string/Capture" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Is not showing the button :s

Thanks alot in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to work out with relative layout with button aligned to parent bottom and your frame layout above it occupying the rest space of the screen.Like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_capture"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_capture"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="snapIt" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It worked, right! I was forgetting the RelativeLayout :s 
THanks alot dude ;)

Answer (score 1):

use the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"

          android:orientation="vertical" >



             <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_capture"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="snapIt"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:text="capture" />
     <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/button_capture"
                 />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

i am just trying to make these layout, after compare my layout code and your layout code, i find a different code, there is  in my code. Did you missing it or just move it away cause it useless from the layout code ?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@id/flayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello_world">
   </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, can you explain better ? Anyway I got my problem solved already